# Socket programming, encode/ decode data/ text, more specific special characters send and receive through sockets

Tags: python, java, c++, sockets

Win 10 64 bit
Server in C++:

```
const int BufLen = 1024;
char RecvBuf[BufLen];
int result;
char SendBuf[BufLen] ;

const int PORT = 27015;
const char* HOST = "127.0.0.1";

int main()
{
    //SetConsoleOutputCP(65001);
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    //std::cout << "á" << std::endl;
    WSADATA wsaData; 
    int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);   if (iResult != NO_ERROR) {
        printf("Error at WSAStartup()\n");     
        return 1;
    }
    // Create a SOCKET for listening for   // incoming connection requests. 
    SOCKET ListenSocket;
    ListenSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Error at socket(): %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());    
        WSACleanup();  
        return 1;
    
    }
    // The sockaddr_in structure specifies the address family,
    // IP address, and port for the socket that is being bound.

    sockaddr_in service;

    service.sin_family = AF_INET;
    //service.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    inet_pton(AF_INET, HOST, &service.sin_addr);
    service.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    if (bind(ListenSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&service, sizeof(service)) == SOCKET_ERROR) { 
        printf("bind() failed.\n"); 
        closesocket(ListenSocket); 
        WSACleanup(); 
        return 1;
    }
    // Listen for incoming connection requests.
    // on the created socket
    if (listen(ListenSocket, 1) == SOCKET_ERROR) { 
        printf("Error listening on socket.\n");
        closesocket(ListenSocket); WSACleanup();
        return 1; 
    }

    // Create a SOCKET for accepting incoming requests. SOCKET AcceptSocket; printf("Waiting for client to connect...\n");
    SOCKET AcceptSocket;
    printf("Waiting for client to connect...\n");

    // Accept the connection.
    AcceptSocket = accept( ListenSocket, NULL, NULL );
    if (AcceptSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("accept failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError()); 
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup(); 
        return 1;
    }
    else printf("Client connected.\n");
    // Call the recvfrom function to receive datagrams 
    // on the bound socket.
    
    printf("Receiving datagrams...\n");
    result = recv(AcceptSocket, RecvBuf, BufLen, 0);
   
    printf("%d\n", result);
    std::cout << "Received:" << RecvBuf << std::endl;
    printf("%d", sizeof(RecvBuf));
    //strcpy_s(SendBuf, "Helloéáőúóü");
    printf("\n\n\n\n");
    strcpy_s(SendBuf, "abcá");
    std::cout << SendBuf << std::endl;
    result = send(AcceptSocket, SendBuf, BufLen, 0);
    printf("\nAfter sending: %d\n", result);
    std::cout << SendBuf;
```

the Java client:

```
 var socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 27015);
        //sending to the server
        var out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        out.println("Helloá");
        //receive from server
        var in = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
        char[] buffer = new char[1024];
        int count = br.read(buffer, 0, 20);
        String reply = new String(buffer, 0, count);
        System.out.println(reply);
```

Python client:

```
HOST = "127.0.0.1"
PORT =  27015
clientSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
clientSocket.connect((HOST, PORT))
clientSocket.send("JAASFSKF".encode('utf-8'))
msg = clientSocket.recv(1024)
print(msg)
msg = msg.decode('utf-8')
print(msg)
clientSocket.close()
```

Ran some experiments with special characters but neither the clients or server can handle it.

The java client result:
[encoding done with utf-8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0mtb.png)
The python app throws and exception because it can not decode the data received from socket:
[Python 3.9.5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDr2t.png)
I tried to save the server in different encoding but i think this is not the case, possibly some changes needed on the socket declaration.
Clients are the same machine as server.
**This is my actual question, to overcome this problem**

Comment: Show error messages as properly formatted text in the question, not as image or external link.

Comment: Python error: "D:\Python stuff\SimpleChatClient\Scripts\python.exe" "D:/Python stuff/SimpleChatClient/main.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python stuff\SimpleChatClient\main.py", line 9, in <module>
    msg = msg.decode('utf-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position 3: invalid continuation byte
b'abc\xe1\x00\xfe\xfe\xfe\xfe\xfe\xfe\xfe\xfe\xfe\xfe\xfe\xfe\xfe\xfe\xfe'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Just adding a note. The proximate cause here is that your C++ code is using the traditional Windows default encoding seen here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252.  That encoding is probably built into the C++ compiler itself. You'll note that the `á` character in that encoding is the single byte hex `e1` (`\xe1`) which matches what your python error message is showing. But `e1` is not part of a valid UTF-8 character. Everything in @user16632363's answer below is correct: when dealing with non-ascii characters in particular, you must be explicit about the encoding.

Answer (score 1):

TCP sockets carry byte streams without interpretation.  There are no "special characters".

Your C++ code is apparently dealing in bytes; your Python and Java code is expecting those bytes to represent "characters" encoded as UTF-8.  This is a design mismatch.

The C++ code should explicitly convert to/from UTF-8 if your intent is that communication use UTF-8.

---

Additionally, there are no "messages" in TCP. It's a byte streaam protocol. You need a convention so that each end can determine whether it has received what your application wants to consider as a message.

If one side sends "xyz" (and does not immediately close the connection), how does the other side know that "z" is the final character?

Since you're dealing in characters, one way would be to make sure everything is terminated by a newline "\n".  The you can use line-oriented methods.

Comment: Actually, the Java client code doesn't specify which character encoding to use.  So it will actually be using the JVM's default character encoding.  That could be UTF-8, or it could be something else.  (Apparently it is UTF-8 on the machine that the OP is currently running the code ...)

Comment: @Stephen C - You're right there.  The "default deffault" is UTF-8, but it would be well for the code to be explicit.